# Jni C++ findclass function return null

Tags: c++, java-native-interface

I found a problem with jni about C calling Java code.
Environment WIN10 JDK1.8
Currently I need C++ code to call Java code. At first I wrote a demothat was successful. Code show as below:

```
public class Sample2 {
    public String name;  
    public static String sayHello(String name) {  
        return "Hello, " + name + "!";  
    }    
    public String sayHello() {  
        return "Hello, " + name + "!";  
    }  
}
```

Some of the C++ code is as follows:

```
int main(){
    printf("hello world");
    JavaVMOption options[3];
    JNIEnv* env;
    JavaVM* jvm;
    JavaVMInitArgs vm_args;

    long status;
    jclass cls;
    jmethodID mid;
    jfieldID fid;
    jobject obj;
    char opt1[] = "-Djava.compiler=NONE";
    char opt2[] = "-Djava.class.path=.";
    char opt3[] = "-verbose:NONE";
    options[0].optionString = opt1; options[0].extraInfo = NULL;
    options[1].optionString = opt2; options[1].extraInfo = NULL;
    options[2].optionString = opt3; options[2].extraInfo = NULL;
    memset(&vm_args, 0, sizeof(vm_args));
    vm_args.version = JNI_VERSION_1_8;
    vm_args.nOptions = 1;
    vm_args.options = options;
    vm_args.ignoreUnrecognized = 0;

    // 启动虚拟机
    status = JNI_CreateJavaVM(&jvm, (void**)& env, &vm_args);

    if (status != JNI_ERR){
        // 先获得class对象
        cls = env->FindClass("Sample2");
    }
}
```

I used Eclipse to compile the Java code into a .class file, copy the .class file into my C++ project, the above DEMO C++ call Java function is successful, and the findclass function returns to normal.

Because I have to introduce a third-party JAR package org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3-1.2.0.jar in my own Java, based on the above example, I modified the Java code in DEMO, but when I want to reference the JAR package function, And then run successfully in Eclipse, when I copy the .class file to the C++ project. JNI_CreateJavaVM in the C++ code is returned successfully, but FINDCLASS always returns null, I don't know why. I have not changed the other parts code.
Some Java code:

```
import javax.net.ssl.TrustManager;
import javax.net.ssl.X509TrustManager; 
import org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.*;
import org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.persist.MemoryPersistence;

public class Sample2 {
    public String name;  
    static MqttAsyncClient mqttClient = null;

    static String username = "xxx";  
    static String password = "xxx"; 
    static String broker = "xxx"; 

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        System.out.print("hello");
    }

    public static void start() {
        String clientId = "mqttserver" + String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis());

        try {
            mqttClient = new MqttAsyncClient(broker, clientId, new MemoryPersistence());

        } catch (Exception me) {
            me.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

When in start function is added
`mqttClient = new MqttAsyncClient(broker, clientId, new MemoryPersistence());` After the code, there will be problems

Comment: You have to add the 3rd-party jar to the classpath (in the `-Djava.class.path=` line)

Comment: Very likely it is a classpath issue -- class `org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttAsyncClient` is not found in the classpath, so initialization of class `Sample2` fails.

Comment: Although your code is written more in the C than the C++ idiom, it does seem to be using the C++ version of the JNI interface, and you do describe it as "C++", so I have modified the tags to replace [c] with [c++].

Comment: Thank you, I copied the third-party jar package to the C++ project, and added this jar after -Djava.class.path=, but this problem still occurs. Is there any other possibility? ?

Comment: What does your `-Djava.class.path=` option line look now? You need to specify both the jar and the current folder as classpaths.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look here

```
char opt1[] = "-Djava.compiler=NONE";
char opt2[] = "-Djava.class.path=.";
char opt3[] = "-verbose:NONE";
options[0].optionString = opt1; options[0].extraInfo = NULL;
options[1].optionString = opt2; options[1].extraInfo = NULL;
options[2].optionString = opt3; options[2].extraInfo = NULL;
memset(&vm_args, 0, sizeof(vm_args));
vm_args.version = JNI_VERSION_1_8;
vm_args.nOptions = 1;
```

You are passing three options (array of options with three options defined) but then, you say something like this

```
vm_args.nOptions = 1;
```

which means you are passing just one option. It means your options

```
char opt2[] = "-Djava.class.path=.";
char opt3[] = "-verbose:NONE";
```

are not even read. You have to change your code to

```
 vm_args.nOptions = 3;
```

Also, make sure to put on `java.class.path` all the `JAR`s, folders, where classes required by your code are.